# What sources /etc/profile?

Tags: profile

I think `/etc/profile` is sourced when the system starts but what sources it? It is not sourced within the `.bashrc` hierarchy when a user logs in. I am using Ubuntu but I believe this is universal across distributions.

Comment: Logs in where? In the GUI? In a TTY? SSH?

Answer (score 2):

`man bash`:

> When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.

So, it's your shell. It gets read before `.bashrc`. There's certainly also shells that just ignore that file, for example, I think `[t]csh` doesn't care about it.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is used by all Bourne-shell compatible shells - including bash, ash, dash, ksh, and zsh. Some of these have other global profile scripts they use in addition to (or instead of) /etc/profile.  They also have per-user profile scripts in ~, which can vary depending on whether the shell is a login shell or not. Or whether they're invoked as `/bin/sh` or not.  It can be complicated. `/etc/profile` **isn't** used by csh or tcsh at all (they use `/etc/csh.cshrc` or `/etc/csh.login` instead, depending on whether they're login or non-login shells) because they're not bourne-compatible.

Comment: @cas You should make that an answer, not a comment.